# Python - Why is len() always return 1 for list

Tags: python

Not sure why len() is returning just 1 as output in Python. Should be 4.

```
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(", ")
num_items = len(names)
print(num_items,",",names,type(names))
```

Output

```
Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. angel,barbara,mary,jjjj
1, ['angel,barbara,mary,jjjj'] <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your input string (`'angel,barbara,mary,jjjj'`) names are separated with commas without spaces (`','`), but you try to split it by comma and space (`', '`). There is no `', '` in the string, so it's not split

Comment: ...thank you it worked now................................Give me everybody's names,separated by a comma. a, b, c
3 , ['a', 'b', 'c'] <class 'list'>

Comment: Glad to hear that, consider marking the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the input on  `,` . remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that there isn't a way to split like this `", "`. the correct way to do so is by removing the space and split like `","`
this is the correct code:

```
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(",")
num_items = len(names)
print(num_items,",",names,type(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split by `","` or separate your input with comma and space.

Comment: please add some code and output.